# Correct way to separate JPA with Service layer

Tags: java, rest, java-ee, persistence, jpa

I have two tables:

```
area (
  id int PK autoincrement
  code varchar
)

products (
  id int PK autoincrement
  name varchar
  area_id int PK to AREA
  ...
)
```

The classes are persisted using eclipselink like this:

```
@Entity
class Product {
    ...
    private Long id;
    ...
    private String name;
    ...
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    @Expose
    private Area area;
    ...    
}
```

This works just fine. But I'm making a rest service for an API, a simple  **PUT** in **http://x.x.x.x/product** where the JSON data should be like this:

```
{
  id: xxx
  name: xxxx
  area: xxxx
}
```

As you can see, I want that the **area** field to be sent differently. **id** and **name** are the same, but in this case the field **area** is the **String** that is in stored in the table.row **area.code**.

Aparently this cannot be made with JPA ( I asked this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086458/linking-two-object-by-code-not-id-using-eclipselink-jpa ) but there, someone said the following:

> Don't mix your entity and webservices classes and you wont have problem like this.

So, I was thinking if I should have two **Product** classes. One for the service layer, the one that the customer will use when they call the API, like this:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String area;
}
```

And then when I'm handling the PUT/GET method just convert this class to the JPA one. something like this:

```
x.jpa.Product jpaProduct = new x.jpa.Product();
jpaProduct.setId(product.getId());
jpaProduct.setName(product.getName());
jpaProduct.getArea().setId( getAreaIdByCode(product.getArea()));
...
m.persist(jpaProduct);
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: *Should I have two Product classes?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve this issue so this approach is not neccesary.

Here is how I did it:

Using transformers. So the field area is defined like this:

```
@Transformation(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@ReadTransformer(transformerClass = AreaAttributeTransformer.class)
@WriteTransformers({
        @WriteTransformer(
                transformerClass = AreaFieldTransformer.class,
                column = @Column(name = "area_id", nullable = false))
})
@Expose
private String area;
```

Then those clases work like this:

**AreaAttributeTransformer**

```
public class AreaAttributeTransformer implements AttributeTransformer {

private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;

@Override
public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping abstractTransformationMapping) {
    this.mapping = abstractTransformationMapping;
}


@Override
public Object buildAttributeValue(Record record, Object o, Session session) {
    for (DatabaseField field : mapping.getFields()) {
        if (field.getName().contains("area_id")) {

            EntityManager em = MyEntityManagerFactory.getENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY().createEntityManager();
            List results = em.createNamedQuery("Areas.findById")
                    .setParameter("id", record.get(field))
                    .getResultList();
            if (results.size() > 0)
                return ((Area) results.get(0)).getCode();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**AreaFieldTransformer**

```
public class AreaFieldTransformer implements  FieldTransformer {

private AbstractTransformationMapping mapping;

@Override
public void initialize(AbstractTransformationMapping abstractTransformationMapping) {
    this.mapping = abstractTransformationMapping;
}

@Override
public Object buildFieldValue(Object o, String s, Session session) {
    if (o instanceof RouSub) {
        EntityManager em = MyEntityManagerFactory.getENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY().createEntityManager();
        List results = em.createNamedQuery("Area.findByCode")
                .setParameter("area", ((Area) o).getCode())
                .getResultList();
        if (results.size() > 0)
            return ((Area)results.get(0)).getId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: However, you still expose the persistence model to the APi. Your data model might change any time and you will have no chances to make changes backward compatibles. Once an API is published, to change its Interface and model is just the hell on Earth. Unless, backward compatibility is not a problem at all. Just curious, what kind of clients do consume the API?

Answer (score 0):

> So, I was thinking if I should have two Product classes. One for the
>   service layer, the one that the customer will use when they call the
>   API.

Well, I think nobody is in a position to say what should you do. It depends pretty much on your requirements but  having different representations is usually a good idea.

For example, the physical representation <sup>1</sup> and the logic <sup>2</sup> are not necessarily the same. And the public  representantation <sup>3</sup> could be a total different one too.

The reason is simple. Decoupling. Having different representations allow us to model every layer with a certain degree of independency with regarding to others, in such a way that, if we change the physical representantation, the change won't necessarily affect the public one.

This is specially important for public Interfaces (API) because once in production, changing interfaces and models lead us to challenging situations. APIs design is specially hard for this reason. We will have to bear the burden of such decisions for good or for bad.

Right now, you are tightly coupling your physical representantation with everything else. Note that if you ever change `Product` the API consumers will suffer the consequences too. At the moment, there's no way for you to guarantee backward compatibility if `Product` changes. Not even versioning, unless you map twice the tables.

If all these stuffs matter or not depends on your specific situation, but at least they worth a mention.

---

<sup>1: The one we store</sup>

<sup>2: The domain data model</sup>

<sup>3: The public</sup>